# In Ember how can I create a component by name programmatically

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I can find lots of examples on how to create a component in Ember programmatically and add it to the DOM like this:

```
var comp = App.FooBarComponent.create();
comp.appendTo('#someArea');
```

But what would you do if you wanted to do it by a name provided?

```
var componentName = 'FooBar';
var comp = ???
comp.appendTo('#someArea');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `component` helper with dynamic `component-name` in template.

```
App.FooComponent = Ember.Component.extend({..});
App.BarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({..});

var dynamicName = 'foo-component';

// template.hbs
<div id="some-area">
  {{component dynamicName}}
</div>
```

See component helper guide here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_component

**UPDATE:** You could use model to provide rendering logic:

```
 // model is array of objects or records array
 <div id="some-area">
   {{#each model as |item| }}
     // component depends on item properties
     {{component item.componentName item=item}}
   {{/each}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you - this is great if I have a single component, but If I'm forced into using appendTo (because I say want an unknown number of components) is there another way too?

Comment: The goal is not clear for me. It looks like it's better to use array of "unknown number" of model instances, wrapped by component that render components for each model instance. You can use dynamic component helper based on model instance properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like...

```
var componentName = 'FooBar';
var comp = App[componentName + 'Component'].create();
comp.appendTo('#someArea');
```

That being said depending on what you are doing there probably is a better way to do whatever you are trying to accomplish.